# How do you break a string of white spaces in html?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have incoming json data that i'm displaying in table cells. Some of these cells contain "reserved white space". And I am able to display and highlight this white space using `pre`/`pre-wrap` and `background-color` properties. But the issue I'm facing is that in some cells, there are way too many white spaces, so it overflows out of the table. Is there a way to break the string after certain number of characters or fix it's width? I have tried fixing the width and max-width of the parent tag. I have also looked for this and there are solutions for breaking strings containing spaces with `pre-wrap` but it doesn't work if there are only white spaces and no other characters. Is there any way/work-around? (I am using angular 10 if it matters.)

Here's what I am trying to do:
The table row in component.html:

```
                    <tr
                      mdbTableCol
                      *ngFor="let item of attr.elements; let k = index"
                    >

                       <ng-container>
                        <td class="small_column_width">
                          
                          <div>
                            <span
                              [ngClass]="{
                                classA: item.status === 'A',
                                classB:
                                  item.status === 'B'
                              }"
                            >
                              {{
                                item.value
                              }}
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </ng-container>
                     </tr>
```

This

```
item.value
```

sometimes returns a series of white spaces that I am able to highlight and show to the end user but it sometimes overflows the table entirely because these values can be 250 characters long. So is there a way to break the string or fix it's width?

component.css:

```
.classA {
  background-color: #4caf50 !important;
  color: whitesmoke;
  max-width: 50px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.classB {
  background-color: #ffbf00 !important;
  max-width: 50px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a piece of code of how did you try to do it. it will help other people to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi Andrei, I thought framing the question in words was enough in this case but I added the code as you said.

Comment: What is a sample string that breaks it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would propose you to first - render it without extra spaces

```
<span ...>{{
   tkt?.records[i]?.attributes[j].elements[k]
     .properties[0].value
}}</span> note that there is no space between }} and <, so no extra spaces would present.
```

second - you can modify the value by maybe some pipe

```
{{
  tkt?.records[i]?.attributes[j].elements[k]
  .properties[0].value | stripManySpaces
}}
```

with some stripping logic inside, something like `return originalString.replace(/\s{4,}/g, '    ')`

Comment: Aaghhh pipes ofcourse! Anyways, thanks a lot man! You literally saved my programatically-handicapped personality!